# Assign variable the key name of True element in a Python dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want a variable to get the key name of the (only) True value in a dictionary, if the key is in a restricted list of keys.

For example, I have a Python dictionary:

```
cli = { 'foo':True, 'bar':False, 'auto':True, 'parse':False }
```

and a list:

```
modes = [ 'auto', 'parse' ]
```

Exactly one of the keys in the list has a True value in the dictionary. I want my variable to get the name of that key.

(Other keys might be True too, but not in the list - in the example `foo` is True.)

In this example, I want a variable `mode` to get the string `'auto'`.

Right now I'm doing it like this (without the list):

```
if   cli['1day']:       mode = '1day'
elif cli['auto']:       mode = 'auto'
elif cli['forceall']:   mode = 'forceall'
elif cli['updateonly']: mode = 'updateonly'
elif cli['force']:      mode = 'force'
elif cli['reparse']:    mode = 'reparse'
elif cli['parse']:      mode = 'parse'
elif cli['mirror']:     mode = 'mirror'
```

Is there a better way (ideally, using the list and without the redundant source code of each key name)?

(FWIW, this is about parsing modes with docopt.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> cli = { 'foo':True, 'bar':False, 'auto':True, 'parse':False }
>>> modes = [ 'auto', 'parse' ]
>>> next(mode for mode in modes if cli[mode])
'auto'
```

Note that this will raise a StopIteration if the iterator doesn't encounter a True value. If this is a possibility, and you would prefer the expression to return `None` instead of crashing, you can supply a default value to next.

```
>>> cli = { 'foo':True, 'bar':False, 'auto':False, 'parse':False }
>>> print(next((mode for mode in modes if cli[mode]), None))
None
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and get the first element:

```
[ m for m in modes if cli[m] ][0]
'auto'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use list comprehension as follows (This will given you an empty list if `value in modes` is not in `cli.keys()`):

```
cli = { 'foo':True, 'bar':False, 'auto':True, 'parse':False }
modes = [ 'auto', 'parse' ]
print ([i for i in cli if i in modes if cli.get(i)])
# Result --> ['auto']
```